# How do I group results of a query if below threshold?

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to get the total number of properties with a certain number of bedrooms in a table which stores all properties and the numbers of bedrooms in each of them. Doing a simple query like:

```
SELECT bedrooms, COUNT(bedrooms)
FROM properties
WHERE city = 'sao_paulo'
GROUP BY bedrooms;
```

or its equivalent in SQLAlchemy:

```
rooms = db.session.query(Properties.bedrooms, func.count(Properties.bedrooms)).filter(Properties.city == location).group_by(Properties.bedrooms).all()
```

returns something like this:

```
+--------+--------+
| Number | Count  |
+--------+--------+
|      0 |    132 |
|      1 |  38089 |
|      2 | 145384 |
|      3 | 201911 |
|      4 |  62070 |
|      5 |   3953 |
|      6 |    769 |
|      7 |    147 |
|      8 |    102 |
|      9 |     47 |
+--------+--------+
```

However, I'd like to get something like this:

```
+--------+--------+
| Number | Count  |
+--------+--------+
| 1-     |  38941 |
| 2      | 145384 |
| 3      | 201911 |
| 4      |  62070 |
| 5+     |   5018 |
+--------+--------+
```

Where results below a certain threshold are grouped with the values either below or above them if they are below a certain threshold. Is there any solution in PostgreSQL to do something like this? And if there is, can it also be written using SQLAlchemy?

Comment: How would you decide when to group below and when above?

Comment: Using a set value as a threshold, something like 10% of the largest value in the table.